# Is there a way to populate a combo with client printers that works in all browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, vbscript

RESUME:
I'm working in making a IE only system in Classic ASP work in Chrome. And in one of the screens i have a combo that have a list of installed printers in client pc populated by a vbscript.

THE PROBLEM:
Edge no longer support VBSCRIPT and Chrome never did, so the vbscript that is doing this function doesn't work in IE neither in Chrome.

THE QUESTION:
Is there a way to populate a combo with client printers that works in all browsers? Or the only way is using browsers printing screen?

(Sorry for english errors, i'm not native)
(I can't put any code for security reasons)

Comment: JavaScript uses the same objects as VBS.

Comment: But activeX objects are no longer supported in EDGE and never was in Chrome.

I need something that can work in all browsers, because the system must print on a paper form, so i need to control the way that prints and things like that.